# jquery timeout function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the `setTimeout` function to set `display: block;` and append to `li`, on mouseover. I just want to remove the block and make it none.

My function works fine but the problem is if the mouse crosses the `li`, it self the block getting visible. How can I avoid this?

my code is:

```
var thisLi;
var storedTimeoutID;

$("ul.redwood-user li,ul.user-list li").live("mouseover", function(){
    thisLi = $(this);

    var needShow = thisLi.children('a.copier-link');

    if($(needShow).is(':hidden')){
        storedTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){
            $(thisLi).children('a.copier-link').appendTo(thisLi).show();
        },3000);
    }
    else {
        storedTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){
            $(thisLi).siblings().children('a.copier-link').appendTo(thisLi).show();
        },3000);
    }   
});

$("ul.redwood-user li,ul.user-list li").live("mouseleave", function(){      
    clearTimeout(storedTimeoutID);

    //$('ul.redwood-user li').children('a.copier-link').hide();
    $('ul.user-list li').children('a.copier-link').hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to say, the code you have given works, so I'm guessing that it's not doing exactly what you want it to do. Could you expand on it a bit more?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: I've edited your answer in an attempt to improve the English and make it more readable.  I just had difficulty with the sentence ending `it self the block getting visible`, could you try and rephrase this so that we might understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your code might start working if You solve the problem with storedTimeoutID variable.

try storing it in `$(this).data('storedtime')`

If the problem remains - it's Your logic. Try reading about [throtting and debouncing](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html) and You'll understand how to fix such problems.